# WaitForExit does not capture the "exit" Input

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have the following method as below, but for some reason, the WaitForExit() is not working or it does not recognize the previous Input line. And it always goes into the *pNpmRun.Kill()* part of the *IF* statement.

I have already tried the Wait time from 0 to 10 mins, with the same result (does not go into *return pNpmRun.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();*). But the actual **"$ newman run ..."** finishes within 3-5 sec.

What I also noticed, if I output the result into a file on the failure - it has different End of output.

When I have the following part:

```
 if (!pNpmRun.WaitForExit(60000))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Postman\\FailedOutput.log", pNpmRun.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                pNpmRun.Kill();
                throw new TimeoutException("Command didn't complete in 10 minute timeout");
            }
```

The output will have the following end (the **'exit'** word is there), and it will also say that Process has already exited when it gets to the .Kill() line:

```
                ... at assertion:0 in test-script                     
                inside "SearchCatalogIndexForNonBatchTracked"     

C:\src\bin\Debug>exit
```

But if I move .ReadToEnd() to be after the .Kill() as below:

```
 if (!pNpmRun.WaitForExit(60000))
            {
                pNpmRun.Kill();
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Postman\\FailedOutput.log", pNpmRun.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                throw new TimeoutException("Command didn't complete in 10 minute timeout");
            }
```

The output will have following end (does not have the **'exit'**):

```
                ... at assertion:0 in test-script                     
                inside "SearchCatalogIndexForNonBatchTracked"
```

And I cannot figure why all of this is happening and not working as I expect.

```
public string Runner ()
    {
        var psiNpm = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        var pNpmRun = Process.Start(psiNpm);
        pNpmRun.StandardInput.WriteLine("npm install -g newman");
        pNpmRun.StandardInput.WriteLine("newman run " +
            "\"C:\\Postman\\Test.postman.json\" " +
            "--folder \"TestSearch\" " +
            "--environment \"C:\\Postman\\postman_environment.json\" " +
            "--disable-unicode");
        pNpmRun.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

        if(!pNpmRun.WaitForExit(600000)) {
             pNpmRun.Kill();
             throw new TimeoutException("Command didn't complete in 10 minute timeout");
         } else {
               return pNpmRun.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
         }
}
```

I expect the code to almost always go into:

```
else {
    return pNpmRun.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: You must always read stdout *while* waiting for the program to exit.  There is a buffer for stdout but it is a small one, usually only 2KB.  So if the program outputs more text than will fit then it will deadlock, waiting for the buffer to get emptied by your code.  That won't happen, your code is waiting for it to exit.  Since you want to do the wait with a timeout you need to use Process.BeginOutputReadLine().

Comment: Thanks @hans-passant, it works for that issue. Sorry but now I have another issue with the .ReadToEnd() part. As it's complaining about "_mixing synchronous and asynchonous operation on process stream_". Do you know how to get around this problem?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use both, now that you fixed your code you don't need ReadToEnd() anymore.

Comment: Thanks @hans-passant, in this case, do you know how I can save all output into a string (then into a file)? I need to have all that output from the command line saved into a file.